# Integral of a function defined with a loop

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, evaluation

I have defined a function `g` as

```
g[t_] := (
   res = 0;
   i = 1;
   While[i <= t,
     res = res + i;
     i = i + 1;
   ];
   res);
```

The aim is to work with the function `F[u]`, which should be the integral of `g` in bounds $[0,u]$, something like

```
F[u_] := Integrate[g[y], {y, 0, u}]
```

However, the result I obtain for `F` is not correct with such definition of `g`. In fact, `F` takes value 0 for any argument `u` (my guess is that this happens because `g[y]` is immediately evaluated as 0).

How can `F` be redefined properly, without changing the definition of `g`?

Comment: Use `g[t_?NumericQ] := ...` instead, then do ```Remove["Global`*"]``` and re-evaluate it. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/72682) for other cases where `NumericQ` is needed.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to simply define `g[t_] := Floor[t] (Floor[t] + 1) / 2`?

Comment: The idea is that `g` is a function defined exactly with a loop. In my research I`m dealing with some counting stochastic process, which cannot be defined otherwise than a sum of random variables upto certain moment. Since stating the whole problem would have been rigorous, I have asked this more general question in order to apply obtained results later in my work.

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to keep the temporary variable names (and values) out of the `Global` context.

```
g[t_] := Module[{res = 0, i = 1},
   While[i <= t, res = res + i; i = i + 1]; res];
```

However, note that `g` evaluates to `0` for symbolic arguments.

```
g[t]

(* 0 *)
```

Consequently, restrict its arguments to being [`NumericQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) or preferably, [`Positive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Positive.html).

```
Clear[g]

g[t_?Positive] := Module[{res = 0, i = 1},
   While[i <= t, res = res + i; i = i + 1]; res];
```

For comparison purposes, define

```
g2[t_] := Module[{m = Floor[t]}, m (m + 1)/2]
```

The argument of `g2` does not need to be restricted.

```
g2[t]

(* 1/2 Floor[t] (1 + Floor[t]) *)
```

Numerically, `g` and `g2` are equivalent for positive arguments.

```
Plot[{g[t], g2[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.25, .75}],
 Exclusions -> Range[10]]
```

[image]

The integrals are

```
F[u_?NumericQ] := Integrate[g[y], {y, 0, u}]

F2[u_?NumericQ] := Integrate[g2[y], {y, 0, u}]

Plot[{F[u], F2[u]}, {u, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.25, .75}]] // Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer!